# How to build and run in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Previously I was using Visual Studio, and now I'm trying to use vscode. Overall I love it, but there are a few functionalities from Visual Studio which I'm missing. Maybe the most important one is a combination of build and run. In Visual Studio when I pressed F5 to run my c++ project, it was performing a build if there were modified files in the project. I can't find that here, I have to manually do a build, then run. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you setup a build task i seem to remember it offers to build when you start debugging

Comment: You can specify a [`preLaunchTask`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) such as doing a build of the project in your "launch.json"

Comment: @UnholySheep that should probably be an answer!